# Pass address bar url of parent window to field in popup

Tags: php

On my website, I have a button which when clicked displays a feedback form in a popup window.

I need to pass the url in the PARENT window to a hidden field in the feedback form.

I tried:

```
<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

<input type="hidden" id="addressBar" name="addressBar" value= "<?php echo $url ?>"/>
```

The problem with the above code is that it passes the url of the current window, in my case, the url of the feedback popup window.

How do I pass the url of the parent window to that hidden field?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Try using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` instead of `REQUEST_URI` (it gives you current uri)
but keep in mind that it's not reliable...

```
$url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'some_default_page.php';
```

Another way could be something like this ...

```
$cur_page_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo '<a href="popup.php?ref='.$cur_page_url.'">Feedback</a>';
```

and then in popup.php just check if `ref` query string is set and retrieve its value.